Convert skewX and skewY to skew-angle and skew-length
I'm parsing transform skewX and skewY to output skew-angle and skew-length – both in degrees.
What I have is this:
const handleSkew = ({
  skewX,
  skewY,
}: Readonly<{ skewX: number, skewY: number }>) => {

  const angle = rad2Deg(Math.atan2(skewY, skewX))
  let length = rad2Deg(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(skewX, 2) + Math.pow(skewY, 2)))

  if (skewX > 0 || skewY < 0) {
    length = -length
  }

  return { length, angle }
}

const rad2Deg = (rad: number) => {
  return (rad * 180.0) / Math.PI
}

This gives me correct direction and angle of skew, but length is slightly off. Can anybody tell be what I'm doing wrong here? 

Length is not measured in degrees, so remove the rad2Deg() wrapped around your sqrt() call.
Also, direction is indicated by the angle not by the length, so you should not be conditionally negating your length.
const handleSkew = ({
  skewX,
  skewY,
}: Readonly<{ skewX: number, skewY: number }>) => {

  const angle = rad2Deg(Math.atan2(skewY, skewX))
  let length = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(skewX, 2) + Math.pow(skewY, 2))

  return { length, angle }
}

const rad2Deg = (rad: number) => {
  return (rad * 180.0) / Math.PI
}


Thank you for your answer. It turns out what I really need is skew direction in degrees and skew amount as an angle in degrees. I thought this was the same as angle and length, but i guess not. How would you go about to further convert the data to achieve this?

How are using skew amount?
To me, the amount as an angle, would just be the absolute value of your direction angle.
